# Use one axis' limit values in another axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, scoping

I'm working on a pgfplots source that plots a (dynamic) data file with different scale of the parallel axis.
This is easy when you know the axis/data range in advance, but what if the range of axis/data isn't known a priori? Let's say that I can't use a wrapper to analyze data and generate the tex source.

The code that follows stores the first couple of axis ranges:

[ \xminA : \xmaxA ], [ \yminA : \ymaxA ]

inside variables, but the scoping of that variables doesn't allow me to use the obtained values for the second axis couple, to set their proper range:

[ \xminB = \xminA * \ratioX : \xmaxB = \xmaxA * \ratioX ], [ \yminB = \yminA * \ratioY : \ymaxB = \ymaxA * \ratioY ]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border={50pt 10pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\ratioX}{2}
\newcommand{\ratioY}{10}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat = newest,
  change x base, change y base,
  scale only axis,
  }
\newcommand*{\datafileLike}{(-3, -3) (2, 2)}
%
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture} [baseline, trim axis left, trim axis right]
    \def\xminA{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}}
    \def\xmaxA{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}}
    \def\yminA{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}}
    \def\ymaxA{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}}
    %
    \begin{axis} [
      xlabel = {\pgfmathprintnumber{\xminA} : \pgfmathprintnumber{\xmaxA}},
      ylabel = {\pgfmathprintnumber{\yminA} : \pgfmathprintnumber{\ymaxA}},
      axis x line* = bottom,
      axis y line* = left,
      width  = 6cm,
      height = 4cm,
      ] \addplot [black] coordinates {\datafileLike};
    \end{axis}
    %
    \begin{axis} [
      axis x line* = top,
      axis y line* = right,
      width  = 6cm,
      height = 4cm,
      % xmin = \xminA * \ratioX,
      % xmax = \xmaxA * \ratioX,
      % ymin = \yminA * \ratioY,
      % ymax = \ymaxA * \ratioY,
      ]
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: graph produced by the source above]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just before the first axis is finished you can record the values globally for the next axis via `after end axis/.code` key.

```
\documentclass[border={50pt 10pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\ratioX}{2}
\newcommand{\ratioY}{10}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat = newest,
  change x base, change y base,
  scale only axis,
  }
\newcommand*{\datafileLike}{(-3, -3) (2, 2)}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture} [baseline, trim axis left, trim axis right]
    %
    \begin{axis} [
      xlabel = {\pgfmathprintnumber{\xminA} : \pgfmathprintnumber{\xmaxA}},
      ylabel = {\pgfmathprintnumber{\yminA} : \pgfmathprintnumber{\ymaxA}},
      axis x line* = bottom,
      axis y line* = left,
      width  = 6cm,
      height = 4cm,
     after end axis/.code={%
     \xdef\xminA{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}}% e(X)panded global (DEF)inition
     \xdef\xmaxA{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}}%
     \xdef\yminA{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}}%
     \xdef\ymaxA{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}}%
     }
      ] \addplot [black] coordinates {\datafileLike};
    \end{axis}
    %
    \begin{axis} [
      axis x line* = top,
      axis y line* = right,
      width  = 6cm,
      height = 4cm,
       xmin = \xminA*\ratioX,
       xmax = \xmaxA*\ratioX,
       ymin = \yminA*\ratioY,
       ymax = \ymaxA*\ratioY,
      ]
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]